# How to replace the arguments of a function?

Tags: functions, replacement, variable

I have the following type of (very long) expression:

$$\ldots + X[1,2,3,5] + X[2,4,5,6] + \ldots \tag{1}$$

where $X[a,b,c,d]$ is some undefined function. I would like to replace all the occurrences of $5$ by $4$ and $6$ by $5$ simultaneously in the argument of $X$, without having to do the replacements one by one. For the example above I should get:

$$\ldots + X[1,2,3,4] + X[2,4,4,5] + \ldots \tag{2}$$

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
expr = X[1, 2, 3, 5] + X[2, 4, 5, 6]
expr /. {5 -> 4, 6 -> 5}

(* X[1, 2, 3, 4] + X[2, 4, 4, 5] *)
```

Note that the order of the rules doesn't matter, here;  according to the [documentation for `ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (which is the function underlying the `/.` infix),

> `ReplaceAll` looks at each part of `expr`, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of `expr`. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.

So even if `6` gets replaced by `5` in one part of the expression, Mathematica will not subsequently replace it by `4` because of the presence of the other rule.

**EDIT:** After I posted the ugly-ass code at the end of this answer, BobHanlon pointed out the much more elegant solution:

```
expr2 /. X[arg__] :> (X[arg] /. {5 -> 4, 6 -> 5})
```

I have left the original code below for posterity.

---

**OLD EDIT:** If `6` or `5` appears in the long expression, the above code will replace it there as well.  If this is undesirable behavior, we need to restrict the action of `ReplaceAll` to anything inside an `X`.  We can do this by using `Position` to find the positions of all of the `X`s in the expression, and then using `MapAt` to apply `ReplaceAll` only to those parts:

```
expr2 = X[1, 2, 3, 5] + 6 X[2, 4, 5, 6];
xpositions = Most /@ Position[expr2, X];
MapAt[ReplaceAll[ {5 -> 4, 6 -> 5}], expr2, xpositions]

(* X[1, 2, 3, 4] + 6 X[2, 4, 4, 5] *)
```

Comment: But numbers might also appear in the expression. What if expr = 6*X[2,4,5,6] ?

Comment: @Pxx: Then you should have included that in the question.  ;-)  That totally makes sense, though, in retrospect.  I'll see what I can figure out that would work and edit this answer appropriately.

Comment: @Pxx:  I think I've now got a version that will only replace the arguments of `X`.

Comment: `expr2 /. X[arg__] :> (X[arg] /. {5 -> 4, 6 -> 5})`

Comment: Oh, FFS.  I was trying that approach with `->` and it didn't work, so I gave up on it.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: slightly shorter: `expr2 /. x_X :> (x /. {5 -> 4, 6 -> 5})`

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes sorry I should have mentioned that this was what I was struggling with!